# Running Tomcat `startup.sh` through ansible reports Tomcat started but it is not

Tags: ansible

This is my task

```
- name: Start the tomcat
  shell: ./startup.sh
  args:
    chdir: /opt/tomcat/bin/
    executable: /bin/bash
  become: yes
```

And this is the result when I run it

```
changed: [172.24.75.19] => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "./startup.sh",
    "delta": "0:00:00.021323",
    "end": "2019-08-08 08:12:40.968951",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "./startup.sh",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": "/opt/tomcat/bin/",
            "creates": null,
            "executable": "/bin/bash",
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2019-08-08 08:12:40.947628",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat\nUsing CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat\nUsing CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp\nUsing JRE_HOME:        /opt/java\nUsing CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar\nTomcat started.",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat",
        "Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat",
        "Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp",
        "Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/java",
        "Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar",
        "Tomcat started."
```

Meanwhile Tomcat is not started on the server.

Comment: What is the evidence that Tomcat  is not running? What happens when you launch the same command manually on the target server ? What do your various logs say (tomcat, system....) ?

Answer (score 2):

Might be you need to add the nohup then it might be work

- name: Start the tomcat
  shell: nohup /path/startup.sh
  args:
  chdir: /opt/tomcat/bin/
  executable: /bin/bash
  become: yes

Comment: `startup.sh` starts tomcat as a daemon, do this is not necessary.